# Why are my PNG images bigger in filesize than the source after upload to magento?

Tags: php, magento, png, magento-1.9, image-uploading

I recently discovered iloveimg.com as a way to genuinely compress my png images before I upload them to my store. However, I have problems uploading the png image as-is:

For example I uploaded [this file which has 17.125 Bytes](https://ibb.co/bx4vJk) to a CMS Page via the insert image feature. After the successful upload, [this file on the server has now 32.287 Bytes](https://ibb.co/iQN4B5). At this point I did not even insert the image to the page, I just uploaded it. To my surprise it almost doubled the filesize. I linked to each file so maybe this helps identifying the issue.

Can anyone explain why this does happen? I suppose it has something to do with the Gd2.php file which unfortunately I cannot fully understand nur handle. I am using magento 1.9.3.4.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: what code exactly? From which file?

Comment: your image upload script of course

Comment: I have never made a custom one by myself. I am just unsing plain magento functionality

Comment: must be a default resize setting somewhere then?

Comment: The uploaded image has been reencoded, from palette (8 bits per pixel) to RGBA (32 bits per pixel)